# Analog signal can be discrete time?

Tags: discrete-signals, continuous-signals, analog

I am new to this site and field too.I always thought analog is continuous and digital signal is discrete. I read this today and got confused about analog signal

> Analog can be 
>   continuous time(CT) or discrete time(DT). A discrete time signal is not a digital signal; a 
>   discrete time signal is one in which the amplitude is a continuum, and not discretized. On 
>   the other hand, if the time is discretized, this signal is still analog. Only when a discrete 
>   time signal is passed through an A to D converter, it becomes a digital signal.

Will anybody explain me what actually it means?

Comment: filters can be made outa *Charge-Coupled Devices* (CCD) a.k.a. "bucket brigade" and would be an example of discrete-time and analog.

Answer (score 7):

This sounds like a confusion in terminology. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digitizing

Digitization basically involves two steps:

1. **Discretization**: Sampling the signal at discrete times
2. **Quantization**: Turning the samples from (in theory) infinite resolution to finite resolution

Look at all possible combinations you can have 4 different types of signal:

1. continuous time, continous amplitude
2. discrete time, continous amplitude
3. continuous time, discrete amplitude
4. discrete time, discrete amplitude

Typically we refer to #1 as "analog" and #4 as "digital". #2 and #3 are of little practical relevance, other than getting the mathematical models right. Quantization and Discretization are really quite different mathematically so it doesn't make a lot of sense to analyze them in combination. In other words: the theory of time discretization applies equally to continuous amplitude and discrete amplitude signals.

Comment: so whether #2 and #3 are combination of analog and digital signal?

Comment: An important case of "almost" #2 in your list is a high precision algorithm implementation, where the quantization is absolutely neglegible (of no consequence to the performance of the algorithm). This is typically a prototype implementation, which may later be transformed into a reduced wordlength implementation to reduce the hardware complexity (make it cheaper).

Comment: Real world #2 is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switched_capacitor

Comment: @user3857907 Take a look at this answer: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/34656/26009